# Can I use a pass value higher than 2 in fstab?

Tags: fstab

The man page for fstab has this to say about the `pass` value:

> Pass (fsck order) Fsck order is to tell fsck what order to check the
>   file systems, if set to "0" file system is ignored.
>
> Often a source of confusion, there are only 3 options :
>
> 0 == do not check. 1 == check this partition first. 2 == check this
>   partition(s) next In practice, use "1" for your root partition, / and
>   2 for the rest. All partitions marked with a "2" are checked in
>   sequence and you do not need to specify an order.
>
> Use "0" to disable checking the file system at boot or for network
>   shares.

It doesn't explicitly mention values higher than 2, but implies that `0`, `1` and `2` are the only useable values.

Other sources (such as the [fsck man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck)) imply that values above `0` will be treated in ascending order ("passno value of greater than zero will be checked in order")

Can values higher than 2 be used, or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is.. it depends, but probably not.

> **TL;DR** if you use `systemd`, non-zero pass numbers will be checked in the order in which they appear in `fstab`. If not `systemd`, pass numbers will be checked sequentially in ascending order and values higher than 2 can be used.

On most distributions of linux, the `fsck` binary is provided by [`util-linux`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux). This `fsck` [accepts pass numbers higher than 2](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/2c308875a7fa1aaa44892c368f6b37bcfcb8879a/disk-utils/fsck.c#L1324-L1368), and these will be treated in order.

**Any system which calls `fsck` directly will understand "pass number" values higher than 2 in `fstab`.**

It turns out that `util-linux`'s `fsck` is not always used to check `fstab`. `systemd` maintains its own internal copy of `fsck` called [`systemd-fsck`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/8a7033ac2f3ac6d30ae7f453074a1ed47243fbf2/meson.build#L2300-L2306), which treats any non-zero `fstab` entries in the order in which they appear (specifically, it will **not** scan your pass number `1` entries before others).

**On linux distributions that use `systemd`**, `systemd-fsck` is used for automated file system checks, and in those cases **the pass number is [treated as a boolean](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/8a7033ac2f3ac6d30ae7f453074a1ed47243fbf2/src/fstab-generator/fstab-generator.c#L393)** (`0` is means "false", or "don't verify" and `!= 0` is true, or "verify").

Also, don't forget that the root drive (the `/` mount) is sometimes checked separately.

Many thanks to [Ned64](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/115138/ned64), who did much research in their [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/547657/72873).

Comment: Thanks for finding this! The question is, is this still the way things work in the `systemd` age, when booting the system and checking the file systems then. Please see my Answer for my own research results.

Comment: @Ned64 interesting, going to update my answer with my findings

Answer (score 2):

No, only 0, 1 and 2 are possible.

From the man page (`man fstab`):

> The sixth field (fs_passno).
>     This field is used by fsck(8) to determine the order in which
>     filesystem checks are done at boot time.  The root filesystem
>     should be specified with a fs_passno of 1.  Other  filesystems  should
>     have a fs_passno  of 2.  Filesystems within a drive will be checked
>     sequentially, but filesystems on different drives will be checked at the
>     same time to utilize parallelism available in the hardware.  Defaults
>     to zero (don't fsck) if not present.

Nowadays (i.e. in the `systemd` age) the `pass_no` entry in `/etc/fstab` seems to be tested against 0 (to disable checking), only, then the `/` (root) file system will be checked first (as if `pass_no == 1`).  All others are treated equally.  Please see [systemd/fsck.c source](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/fsck/fsck.c) and [systemd//fstab-generator.c source](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/fstab-generator/fstab-generator.c) for details (or rather, missing tests of `pass_no` except against 0).

That means that while you could write other numbers like 17 these would only be tested against 0 and the exact value would otherwise be ignored.

Comment: I don't think "should" is the same as "must".

Comment: @CodeBling I researched and added links to the source code. Please check and confirm (or comment) to see whether you read the same from the source as I.

Comment: I updated my answer with the information I found. Nice job finding this. It's strange that `systemd` maintains its own `fsck` binary which doesn't operate the same way as the default one.

Comment: It's interesting that the manual is wrong in both cases. It says "there are only 3 options", but with `util-linux` any value above zero works (there are many options), and with `systemd-fsck`, all non-zero values are the same (there are only 2 options).